# I cannot initialize my project on Visual Studio Code using the PlatformIO

Tags: visual-studio-code, embedded, platformio

I am using Visual Studio Code and added the PlatformIO IDE extension along with c/c++ to code for my board, which is a uPesy ESP32 Wrovoer DevKit with a Espressif IoT Developement framework. Everything matches my but when I click finish I get an error message:

```
The current working directory C:\Users\brownme1\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\my_project will be used for the project.

The next files/directories have been created in C:\Users\brownme1\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\my_project
include - Put project header files here
lib - Put here project specific (private) libraries
src - Put project source files here
platformio.ini - Project Configuration File
Resolving upesy_wrover dependencies...
Already up-to-date.
Updating metadata for the vscode IDE...

Error: Processing upesy_wrover (platform: espressif32; board: upesy_wrover; framework: espidf)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Verbose mode can be enabled via -v, --verbose option
CONFIGURATION: https://docs.platformio.org/page/boards/espressif32/upesy_wrover.html
PLATFORM: Espressif 32 (6.0.0) > uPesy ESP32 Wrover DevKit
HARDWARE: ESP32 240MHz, 320KB RAM, 4MB Flash
DEBUG: Current (cmsis-dap) External (cmsis-dap, esp-bridge, esp-prog, iot-bus-jtag, jlink, minimodule, olimex-arm-usb-ocd, olimex-arm-usb-ocd-h, olimex-arm-usb-tiny-h, olimex-jtag-tiny, tumpa)
PACKAGES: 
 - framework-espidf @ 3.50000.0 (5.0.0) 
 - tool-cmake @ 3.16.4 
 - tool-esptoolpy @ 1.40400.0 (4.4.0) 
 - tool-idf @ 1.0.1 
 - tool-mconf @ 1.4060000.20190628 (406.0.0) 
 - tool-ninja @ 1.9.0 
 - toolchain-esp32ulp @ 1.23500.220830 (2.35.0) 
 - toolchain-xtensa-esp32 @ 11.2.0+2022r1
Reading CMake configuration...
-- Could NOT find Git (missing: GIT_EXECUTABLE) 
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
-- Found assembler: C:/Users/brownme1/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/brownme1/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Users/brownme1/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe -- broken
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/brownme1/Documents/PlatformIO/Projects/my_project/.pio/build/upesy_wrover/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/brownme1/Documents/PlatformIO/Projects/my_project/.pio/build/upesy_wrover/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

CMake Warning at C:/Users/brownme1/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/tools/cmake/git_submodules.cmake:4 (message):
 Git executable was not found. Git submodule checks will not be executed.
 If you have any build issues at all, start by adding git executable to the
 PATH and rerun cmake to not see this warning again.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
 C:/Users/brownme1/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/tools/cmake/idf.cmake:41 (include)
 C:/Users/brownme1/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/tools/cmake/project.cmake:12 (include)
 CMakeLists.txt:2 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Users/brownme1/.platformio/packages/tool-cmake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
 The C compiler

 "C:/Users/brownme1/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe"

 is not able to compile a simple test program.

 It fails with the following output:

 Change Dir: C:/Users/brownme1/Documents/PlatformIO/Projects/my_project/.pio/build/upesy_wrover/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
 
 Run Build Command(s):C:/Users/brownme1/.platformio/packages/tool-ninja/ninja.exe cmTC_0ae29 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles\cmTC_0ae29.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj

 FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_0ae29.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj 

 C:\Users\brownme1\.platformio\packages\toolchain-xtensa-esp32\bin\xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe -mlongcalls -Wno-frame-address -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_0ae29.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj -c testCCompiler.c

 xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe: fatal error: cannot execute 'c:/users/brownme1/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/11.2.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/as.exe': CreateProcess: No such file or directory
 compilation terminated.

 ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

 
 

 

 CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
 C:/Users/brownme1/.platformio/packages/framework-espidf/tools/cmake/project.cmake:342 (__project)
 CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)



========================== [FAILED] Took 4.21 seconds ==========================
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to read the error carefully. It says you're missing [git](https://git-scm.com/downloads).

```
Git executable was not found. Git submodule checks will not be executed.
 If you have any build issues at all, start by adding git executable to the
 PATH and rerun cmake to not see this warning again.
```